# How to use of lambda for custom SingleObserver

Tags: java, android, lambda, rx-java, retrofit

I have this customized SingleObserver class:

```
public abstract class SubscribeWithView<T> implements SingleObserver<T>,Disposable {


    private WeakReference<RootView> rootView;


    /**
     * <p style="color:blue;">set view from presenter</p>
     *
     * @param rootView
     *{@link RootView}
     */

    public SubscribeWithView(RootView rootView) {
        this.rootView = new WeakReference<>(rootView);
    }


    ...
}
```

And so I use  below code in API repository interface class:

```
@POST(ApiAddress.USER_LOGIN)
    Single<Response<UserWithToken>> userLogin(@Body UserLogin_request userLogin_request);
```

My question is: How to change this code:

```
.subscribe(new SubscribeWithView<Response<UserWithToken>>(view) {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Response<UserWithToken> response) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {
                            super.onError(e);
                        }
```

to lambda like this?

```
apiRepository.userLogin(request)
                .subscribe(new SubscribeWithView<Response<UserWithToken>>(view) {
                    response->{},e->{});
```

Comment: Why don't you use `subscribe(Consumer, Consumer)` and simply let the lambda-capture have the `view` for you, which you can access from both lambdas.

Answer (score 0):

No, Java supports lambdas only for "functional interfaces". Basically that means you cannot use lambda with more than one method to implement.

Answer (score 0):

instead of retrofit single you can use Rxjava single like this:

your interface :

```
    @GET("somehing")
   Single<UserWithToken> getUserWithTokenFromServer(@Query("something") String  something);
```

your Implementation:

```
apiClient.getUserWithTokenFromServer("123456")
    .subscribe(UserWithToken -> {
        // handle data fetched successfully and API call completed
    },Throwable::printStackTrace);
```